# place results of each foreach objects into their own columns

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an array of objects that I am getting values for using foreach:

```
foreach($type as $value){
    $value->Type;
};
```

If I `ECHO` this, I get results like:

```
type1
type2
type3
etc.
```

**The mysql is**

```
$type = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT Type FROM mytablename"));
```

Great! Now since they are objects, if I wanted to get a count on each variation of the type and display that in a table how would I do that?

I have tried adding things like `SELECT COUNT(Type), type FROM mytablename` or the like and then using my `FOREACH` loop but that is invalid.

I know how to build a table in PHP with `ECHO '<table>' .... '</table>'` but don't know what I am using for the variable in the `TD` of each in order to achieve this.

**Desired Result:**

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ type1 +++ type2 +++ type3 +++ type4 +
+   2   +++  3    +++   1   +++  5    +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Please show the code from the querying of the database to the foreach

Comment: added the mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use several built in array functions to get the result you want. By using array_map, we can get the property Type of each object.
We can then use array_count_values to get the frequency of each type.

```
<?php

$frequencies = array_count_values(
    array_map(
        function ($v) {
            return $v->Type;
        },
        $type
    )
);

ksort($frequencies,  SORT_NATURAL);

?>
```

Finally, the table can be rendered using PHP as follows using both array_keys which will return the unique types. While array_values will return the matching frequencies.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach (array_keys($frequencies) as $type) : ?>
            <th><?= $type ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach (array_values($frequencies) as $frequency) : ?>
            <td><?= $frequency ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked like a charm. I had tried to use `foreach` key-> value etc but being an object made that all harder. This solution is clean and elegant.

Comment: A follow up question is how I would retain the types even if the count is zero with this set up?

Comment: @Kris This depends a bit on how your application and database are set up. In case all the possible types are stored in a separate table in the database this would be most reliable and easiest to maintain through the database.

Comment: @Kris You could do several things. (1) Have the database count the frequency of each type and union the set of types not present in the other set and give them a value of 0 for count.

Comment: @Kris (2) If you have access to all of the types in the code already, you could add those not in `$frequencies` to `$frequencies` before they are sorted by keys as `$frequencies['typeN'] = 0;`

Comment: Thanks so much. I was staying away from a MYSQL count and display since it changes the way everything is laid out to date. For adding it in the current code using `$frequencies['typeN'] = 0;` I am not clear as to where that goes. I would have thought it would go just before the ksort line so it can be sorted but when added there, it is added to the table with the count of '0' as it should but without a title. If I am needing to add before the keys, where then would this go?